# Eclipse and Aptana

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I am trying to install Aptana in my eclipse, eclipse version info says: 
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

I pasted http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install in install new software option. However I get following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.jee 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Runtime 3.7.0.v20110110 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0.v20110110)
    Core Runtime 3.9.100.v20131218-1515 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.9.100.v20131218-1515)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Core 3.6.0.1402537589-B27k88Bma9kxYA5ZR9833355984B (com.aptana.feature.feature.group 3.6.0.1402537589-B27k88Bma9kxYA5ZR9833355984B)
    To: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C)
    To: com.aptana.feature.feature.group [3.6.0.1402537589-B27k88Bma9kxYA5ZR9833355984B]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.jee 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.4.2.20120213-0813]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse CSS SWT Theme Support 0.9.100.v20130515-1857 (org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.9.100.v20130515-1857)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.2.v20120120-1424-9DB5FmnFq5JCf1UA38R-kz0S0272]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.7.2.v20120120-1424-9DB5FmnFq5JCf1UA38R-kz0S0272 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120120-1424-9DB5FmnFq5JCf1UA38R-kz0S0272)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0.v20110110]
```

Please Help !!!

Comment: Use the current version of Eclipse as the starting point, Luna SR1. Indigo is out of date. I really don't understand why anyone would start with a version other than what's current.

Comment: Maybe because Eclipse users are sick of reinstralling Eclipse from scratch every year. Update from Kepler to Luna is currently broken